# PotgreSQL- ERROR: invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xeb 0x6e 0x74

Tags: postgresql, encoding, character-encoding, pgadmin-4

I am working on PostgreSQL and getting below error during insert statement execution from batch script(command line).

> ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xeb 0x6e 0x74

I have checked client_encoding by `show client_encoding` command and it is showing UTF-8.

Also checked database properties by using command

`select * from pg_database where datname='<mydbName>'`

**In Output**:

`datcollate = English_United States.1252
 datctype = English_United States.1252`

How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the three bytes quoted by the error message are supposed to encode the string “ënt”, you can solve your problem by setting the correct client encoding, e.g.

```
SET client_encoding = WIN1252;
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. This also didn't work. Actually when i execute insert query from query browser(pgAdmin4) then it executed successfully but when I execute the same command from batch script (Command line) then it gives me the error. So shall I have to set anything in batch script?  Word:  ** e.g. patiënt **

Comment: Yes, you have to include the `SET` statement in the batch script. Depending on which client you are using, there may be more elegant ways of setting the client encoding, but the `SET` statement is the fool-proof way.

Answer (score 0):

This happened because you have special characteres in the name of the columns.
Rename and delete special characters change the encoding for win-1252 and will work.